# Separating OData from data layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a website which is created in MVC5 with no webapi controllers just plain MVC.

We use 3 projects: `MVC`, `Business` and `DataLayer`.

The MVC holds the MVC projects, controllers, views, viewmodels etc.

The businesslayer is injected into the constructors of the Controllers of the MVC project.

In the businesslayer some common checks are done, but mostly it tries to do CRUD to a database.

The EF is located in the datalayer project. This project is injected in the businesslayer again.

Making it this way we can test each project separately with mocking. The data project opens a `DataContext`, performs a CRUD operation, closes the connect and returns the result to the business layer which returns the result again to the MVC project / Controller.

Now the problem. The project has changed because of the need for offline capabilities and I started to use AngularJS + JayData. JayData provides a simple odata implementation and I would like to start using OData to get information to the frontend.

I added a new OData webAPI controller and I immediately see that it wants to use the `DataContext` in the API controller. This is not the behavior I want because it's untestable. I tried converting my controller to become like this:

```
    public IQueryable<ItemViewModel> GetItem()
    {
        var items = _items.Get();
        return (IQueryable<ItemViewModel>) items;
    }
```

`_items.Get()` will do a call to the business layer which asks the DB for all the `Items` where the business layer converts them into `ItemViewModel`.

Problem is that OData expects an open `DataContext` so it can it's queries,  but now it won't work because I close the `DataContext` early.

How can I make this testable?

Comment: More code would be appreciated, but is _items a datacontext?

Comment: No it is not. _items is an interface with implementation which returns a simple `IEnumerable<ItemViewModel>()`

Comment: Do you use a using statement in your crud method? Like using (var context = new DataContext())?

Comment: Yes, it opens and closes the datacontext right away.

Comment: If you are using Unity, give this a go. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337023(v=pandp.30).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this article which clears up alot of things.

http://roysvork.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/is-using-odataiqueryable-in-your-web-api-an-inherently-bad-thing/

I stopped using the `EntitySetController` and implemented my own `ODataController` which I can tie down much more.

Comment: So how do you sort this out? How do you implement ODataController to suit this situatiion?

Comment: I used http://linqtoquerystring.net/ to convert the OData query to EF and use that. Basically you are passing it straight to the data layer, not great but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up with storing entity data into Memory and change the `OData` signature as following :

```
public class ProjectsController : ODataController
{
        // GET: odata/Projects
        [EnableQuery]
        public IHttpActionResult GetProjects()
        {
            var projects = ProjectManager.GetProjects();
            return Ok(projects.AsQueryable());
        }
}
```

This way we do not need to tight the UI layer to Data Access layer.

http://www.odata.org/blog/how-to-use-web-api-odata-to-build-an-odata-v4-service-without-entity-framework/